# c# globally localize date time across application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, datetime-format

I have a .NET c# and need to get the local time of every datetime field that is displayed to the end user to be the user's local time.
is there a way to handle this globally w/o having to modify each place a datetime is displayed?

the system times are set to UTC, and all data is stored and returned as UTC.

an example would be, if the time in the system that is returned to the application is 1600hrs UTC, a user sitting in eastern time should see this time as 1200hrs, and a user sitting in

i've seen some solutions that use js, but this is not an option for us

thanks for the help

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking... To me "system times are set to UTC" means that UTC *is local time* - what other local time you are looking for? Also "IIS" is somewhat strange tag - possibly you mean "this is web server code in custom non-ASP.Net framework" - you may want to [edit] post and clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the user's local, in a cookie or database, you need to store two values to help you in the i18n (internationalization), then, when you need to format something make use of this two classes of c#: [TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397765(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397765(v=vs.110).aspx), the first need the country timezone and the second needs the timezone (you can see all the time zones with `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, then you use this classes to format your texts.

An example:

```
var timeZoneInfo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.CountryTimezone) ?
        TimeZoneInfo.Local :
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Settings.CountryTimezone);
var cultureInfo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.CountryCulture) ?
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture :
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Settings.CountryCulture);
```

Then you use this objects like this:

```
var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(client.ActivatedOn.Value.UtcDateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

And in a view (for example):

```
@dateTime.ToString("G", cultureInfo)
```

With this you will be showing the user not only the correct date (despite the Daylight Saving in the country), but in the local format.